# Find the Odd-one-outs then Leave the Twins

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, odd-one-out

> so you can answer **What are These?**

[image: Find the Odd-one-outs then Leave the Twins]

Comment: what are those.... XD

Comment: Mamma mia, where to begin... +1! :P

Comment: Some progress (rot13): R vf gur fnzr nf H, naq rirel bgure cnggrea vf havdhr.  Fb V guvax R naq H ner gur gjvaf naq gur bguref ner gur bqq barf bhg. Ohg V fgvyy qba'g xabj jung gurfr ner.

Comment: Bs pbhefr, gura, yrsg gur gjvaf jbhyq ersre gb P naq G.

Comment: Minor edit, RIP my grammar :(

Comment: If anyone wants a list of the missing ones, here it is: rot13(o, q, w, x, z, c, d, i, k, l, m)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are these your

> **FLOWCHARTINGS?**

Because

> this is the word that forms when I connect letters that are one *difference* apart, ignoring E and U, which are identical *twins*.
>  [image]

Comment: Great works! Btw, the intended solution is like this: rot13(Svaq n cvpgher (sebz 15) juvpu unf rknpgyl n fvatyr pryy/ryrzrag qvssrerag guna gur bguref, fb vg'f S (gbc-evtug pryy). Gura, qb gur fnzr guvat sbe gur erfg 14, jr jvyy trg Y. Nsgre gung, vgrengviryl sbe gur erfg 13, 12, naq fb ba hagvy 3 nf lbh pna'g qb gung guvat sbe gur erfg 2 va gur raq.)

Comment: Well I had initially looked for rot13(juvpu pryyf va rnpu vzntr qvssrerq sebz gur znwbevgl, naq gura abgvprq gung gur pbyyrpgvbaf bs "reebef" va rnpu cvpgher frrzrq gb or fhofrgf bs rnpu bgure, fb V raqrq hc jvgu n gjb-jnl pbagnvazrag punva pbagnvavat gur arprffnel yrggref. Nyfb, jnl gb uvqr lbhe anzr va gurer.) ;)